# foundation 5 right-to-left support

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Does anyone know if there is a version of foundation 5 framework with RTL support? I found one that is RTL but it was version 4 ([here](http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-rtl)). If there isn't any for foundation 5, what does it take to manually configure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/rtl.html) explain how rtl-support for Foundation works. If you are not using Sass you can download the foundation.css with right to left support there, too.

Comment: Where is the link to rtl-foundation.css?

Comment: At the end of the page: "If you prefer vanilla CSS, use the customizer to download Foundation and get right-to-left support. Your download should be ready to use without any of the steps mentioned above…"

Comment: @chrona I cannot download

Comment: It seems that links changed after Foundation 6 was released. You might want to contact them and ask for the new link!